# How to find duplicate parameter and consider one which contains value in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to find duplicate parameters and then consider the one which has value and eliminate the duplicate one which does not contain value.

Scenario 1 - Suppose I have parameters like `firstname, lastname, firstname,middlename`
and the value is like `firstname=`, `lastname=con`, `firstname=abc`, `middlename=`

And
decryptedRequest is something like

`lastname=con&firstname=&firstname=abc&middlename=`

Scenario 2 - Suppose I have parameters like `firstname, lastname, firstname,middlename`
and the value is like `firstname=test`,`lastname=con`, `firstname=abc`,`middlename=`

decryptedRequest is something like

`lastname=con&firstname=test&firstname=abc&middlename=`

```
   private NameValueCollection parameters;
            
    foreach (var parameter in parameters)
    {
                            
        if (IsDuplicatedParam(parameter.ToString(), decryptedRequest))
        {
           LogManager.Publish(LogTypes.Exception | LogTypes.Error, "Duplicate parameter " + parameter + " received in request : " + decryptedRequest);
                    return false;
         }           
    }
            
    private bool IsDuplicatedParam(string parameter, string decryptedRequest)
    {       
        var requestWithoutParameter = decryptedRequest.Replace(parameter + "=", "");
        if (decryptedRequest.Length - requestWithoutParameter.Length > parameter.Length + 1)
            return true;
            return false;
    }
```

In my first scenario, out of duplicate parameter, it should only return that has value and ignore the duplicate with blank.

- Expected output should be, `lastname=con`, `firstname=abc`,`middlename=`

In my second scenario, both duplicate parameters have values so ignore and return and log an error.

- Expected output should be, `Bad request`

But I would like to combine all these logic in my `IsDuplicatedParam` method.

if there are duplicate parameters and those both parameters have values then return false. But, If either one of the parameter has value then return true. In my code, `IsDuplicatedParam()` always return true. So I would like to rewrite my `IsDuplicatedParam` in such a way that it handles my scenarios.

Comment: `NameValueCollection` has `.GetValues` method to get all the values for a given key...

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, can you please show me solution.

Comment: To clarify: is your goal to find the first non-empty value for each parameter as a dictionary of key to value?

Comment: @testtest - That's a weird requirement given the name of the method.

Comment: @Enigmativity - I understand that but that is what I need to achieve. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
parameters.Add("firstname", "");
parameters.Add("lastname", "bbb");
parameters.Add("firstname", "ccc");

IEnumerable<string> pairs =
    from key in parameters.Cast<String>()
    from value in parameters.GetValues(key).Where(x => x != "").Take(1)
    select $"{key}={value}";

Console.WriteLine(String.Join("&", pairs));
```

That outputs `firstname=ccc&lastname=bbb`.

Comment: How to add your code in my code. Do I need to remove `IsDuplicatedParam()` ?

Comment: @testtest What do you actually need as the result? This is currently absent from your question, so it would be a little difficult for Enigmativity to show you how to integrate it with your current code. This is also why I haven't provided an answer for you: I don't know how you need the result.

Comment: @testtest - Your questions asks to output only the non empty strings, but your `LogManager.Publish` code seems to only want the empty strings. You need to be clear on what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @Enigmativity - My expectation is that if there are duplicate parameters and those both parameters have values then return false. But, If either one of the parameter has value then return true. In my code, `IsDuplicatedParam()` always return `true`. So I would like to rewrite my `IsDuplicatedParam` in such a way that it handles my scenarios.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama - Please see in the question. I have added my expectation.

Answer (score 0):

you could implement like this.

```
string str = "lastname=con&firstname=&firstname=abc";
var arr = str.Split('&');
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    int index = arr[i].IndexOf('=');
    string item = arr[i].Substring(0, index);

    if (dict.ContainsKey(item) == false)
    {
        string value = arr[i].Substring(index);
        if (value != "=")
            dict.Add(item, value);
    }
}
```

It will give you a dictionary with keys as `firstname` and `=con` as value. you could modify the cod eif you want to get rid of `=` in the value

Comment: My expectation is that if there are duplicate parameters and those both parameters have values then return false. But, If either one of the parameter has value then return true. In my code, `IsDuplicatedParam()` always return true. So I would like to rewrite my IsDuplicatedParam in such a way that it handles my scenarios